# JS restore preventDefaults

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to restore defaults in events.
So, for example I have some eventlistener:

```
const tabTouchmoveEvent = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
// setting passive: false, so I can do preventDefault thing
window.addEventListener('touchmove', tabTouchmoveEvent, { passive: false });
```

Then, when time comes, I need to restore it:

```
window.removeEventListener('touchmove', tabTouchmoveEvent);
```

But It WON'T do restoring defaults!

Why that is happens and how can I restore/remove js events?

Comment: You need to pass the same signature in both add and remove eventListener

Comment: I'm passing it - tabTouchmoveEvent. The problem is not unattaching event - the issue is restoring defaults for event

Comment: What do you mean restore it if not removing the event that prevents it? Your line with the removeEventListener does nothing, because tou need to pass {passive:false} there too.

Comment: It does nothing even if I put passive:false to removeeventlistener. BTW: typescript against it for some reason

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an clear description of what you are trying to do and a [mcve]. "restore defaults in events" is not clear, what default behavior are you trying to restore, and how do you ensure it's been restored or not?